# How can one change the set up in condor so that users don't have to chmod their experiment scripts?

Tags: hpc, condor

Currently users of the condor cluster have to do:

```
chmod a+x /home/user/automl-meta-learning/results_plots/main.py
```

to be able to run their scripts with condor_submit. How can the condor set up be made so that users don't have to do that anymore?

---

bonus here is a user sample submission script:

```
####################
#
# Experiments script
# Simple HTCondor submit description file
#
# chmod a+x test_condor.py
# chmod a+x experiments_meta_model_optimization.py
# chmod a+x meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
# chmod a+x download_miniImagenet.py
# chmod a+x ~/meta-learning-lstm-pytorch/main.py
# chmod a+x /home/user/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/meta_learning/datasets/rand_fc_nn_vec_mu_ls_gen.py
# chmod a+x /home/user/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/supervised_experiments_submission.py
# chmod a+x /home/user/automl-meta-learning/results_plots/main.py
# condor_submit -i
# condor_submit job.sub
#
####################

# Executable = /home/user/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/supervised_experiments_submission.py
Executable = /home/user/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/experiments/meta_learning/meta_learning_experiments_submission.py
# Executable = /home/user/meta-learning-lstm-pytorch/main.py
# Executable = /home/user/automl-meta-learning/automl-proj/meta_learning/datasets/rand_fc_nn_vec_mu_ls_gen.py

## Output Files
Log          = experiment_output_job.$(CLUSTER).log.out
Output       = experiment_output_job.$(CLUSTER).out.out
Error        = experiment_output_job.$(CLUSTER).err.out

# Use this to make sure 1 gpu is available. The key words are case insensitive.
REquest_gpus = 1
requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Quadro RTX 6000")

# requirements = ((CUDADeviceName = "Tesla K40m")) && (TARGET.Arch == "X86_64") && (TARGET.OpSys == "LINUX") && (TARGET.Disk >= RequestDisk) && (TARGET.Memory >= RequestMemory) && (TARGET.Cpus >= RequestCpus) && (TARGET.gpus >= Requestgpus) && ((TARGET.FileSystemDomain == MY.FileSystemDomain) || (TARGET.HasFileTransfer))
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Tesla K40m")
# requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "GeForce GTX TITAN X")

# Note: to use multiple CPUs instead of the default (one CPU), use request_cpus as well
Request_cpus = 4
# Request_cpus = 16

# E-mail option
Notify_user = me@gmail.com
Notification = always

Environment = MY_CONDOR_JOB_ID= $(CLUSTER)

# "Queue" means add the setup until this line to the queue (needs to be at the end of script).
Queue
```

Answer (score 0):

The .py files need to have the execute bits set if you are going to execute them directly, this is a Linux/Unix idiom, and has little to do with HTCondor.  That is, on the command line, if you want to run

```
$ ./foo.py
```

foo.py needs the executable bit set.  If you want to work around this, you can pass foo.py as an argument to python, and run

```
$ python foo.py
```

Then the executable bit doesn't need to be set.  To mimic this in HTCondor, you can set /usr/bin/python or /usr/bin/python3 as your executable, and set foo.py as your argument, e.g.

```
executable = /usr/bin/python
arguments = foo.py
```

This all assumes that you have a shared filesystem.  If you are using HTCondor's file transfer to send data to the worker node, there are a couple more lines.

Comment: when I execute with sbatch my python scripts directly I never ever have to do a chmod. Like ever. Only with condor. How do we stop condor from requiring this?